# Проблемы при использовании библиотеки JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Пробую парсить сайт, но переменные `title`, `description`, `image`, `link`, `dateTime`, `comment` пустые.

Что я делаю не так?

```
public class Article extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<ArticleColumn>> {
    ArrayList<ArticleColumn> articleColumns = new ArrayList<>();

    Elements contentTitle;
    Elements contentDescription;
    Elements contentImage;
    Elements contentLink;
    Elements contentDateTime;
    Elements contentComment;

    Element content;

    String title;
    String description;
    String image;
    String link;
    String dateTime;
    String comment;

    Document doc = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ArticleColumn> doInBackground(Object... voids) {

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dev.by").get();

            contentTitle = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__title");
            contentDescription = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__description");
            contentImage = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__image > img[src]");
            contentLink = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__title__link");
            contentDateTime = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__info__datetime");
            contentComment = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__footer");

            for (int i = 0; i < contentTitle.size(); i++) {
                content = contentTitle.get(i);
                title = content.text();

                content = contentDescription.get(i);
                description = content.text();

                content = contentImage.get(i);
                image = content.attr("abs:src");

                content = contentLink.get(i);
                link = content.attr("abs:href");

                content = contentDateTime.get(i);
                dateTime = content.text();

                content = contentComment.get(i);
                comment = content.text();
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + title);

                articleColumns.add(new ArticleColumn(title, description, dateTime, image, comment, link));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: articleColumns " + articleColumns);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return articleColumns;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArticleColumn> stringArrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(stringArrayList);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(articleColumns);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные у Вас *пустые*, так как `contentTitle.size()` равен нулю и цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < contentTitle.size(); i++) {...}
```

не выполняется ни разу.

`contentTitle.size()` равен нулю, так как в строке:

```
contentTitle = doc.select(".articleColumn-preview__title");
```

метод `select(...)` возвращает пустой объект `Elements`.

В свою очередь, метод `select(...)` возвращает пустой `Elements`, так как на заданной странице нету элементов, соответствующих селектору `.articleColumn-preview__title`.

---

Получить заголовки статей с приведенной страницы можно так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dev.by").get();
Elements contentTitle = doc.select("a.article-preview__title__link");
```

А еще у `Jsoup` есть такой весьма полезный сервис – https://try.jsoup.org/.

Comment: все понял, спасибо, ошибка была в неправильно указанных тегах